# jQuery countdown stopping page from showing

Tags: jquery, pagination, countdown

I am not sure whats happening, but I am setting the newcontent and trying to add a countdown to each item however It seems not to be working, Sorry not quite sure how to explain it.

with out the count down part of this script see below the script works fine

COUNT DOWN PART

```
$('#countdown'+members[i]['id]']).countDown({
                            targetDate: {
                            'day':      17,
                            'month':    12,
                            'year':     2012,
                            'hour':     01,
                            'min':      0,
                            'sec':      0,
                            },omitWeeks: true

                        });
```

and the html side of the script

```
function realcashNowCallback(page_index, jq){
                // Get number of elements per pagionation page from form
                var items_per_page = 8;
                var max_elem = Math.min((page_index+1) * items_per_page, members.length);
                var newcontent = '';

                // Iterate through a selection of the content and build an HTML string
                for(var i=page_index*items_per_page;i<max_elem;i++)
                {

                    memberscountdown = members[i]['enddate'];
                    newcontent += '<div id="offer1" class="realcashnowitems">'+
                                  '<div id="title1" class="moreofferstop">' + members[i]['tradingname'] + '</div>'
                                 +' <div id="defaultCountdown" class="moreoffers"> '
                                 +'<div id="pic1" class="productimagesmall"><img style="width:180px;" src="'+ members[i]['picurl']+'"></div>'
                                 +'<div id="description1" class="descriptionsmall">'+ members[i]['des']+'</div>'
                                 +'<div id="spend1_0" class="spendget1">SPEND $'+members[i]['offers'].split('|')[0].replace('.00', '').replace(' $', '')+'<br/><span>GET $'+members[i]['offers'].split('|')[1].split(',')[0].replace(' $', '').replace('.00', '')+'</span></div>'
                                 +'<div id="countdown'+members[i]['id']+'"class="spendget2">';


                    newcontent += '</div>'
                                 +'<div class="buttonmore"><a id="link1" href="'+ members[i]['url'] +'"><img src="template/images/elmos/More_Button.png"></a></div> '           
                                 +'</div>'
                                 +'<div id="sub1" class="moreoffersbottom">'+ members[i]['suburb']+'</div>'
                                 +'</div>';     

                    $('#countdown'+members[i]['id']).countDown({
                        targetDate: {
                        'day':      17,
                        'month':    12,
                        'year':     2012,
                        'hour':     01,
                        'min':      0,
                        'sec':      0,
                        },omitWeeks: true

                    });

                }

                // Replace old content with new content
                $('#Searchresult').html(newcontent);

                // Prevent click eventpropagation
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: isn't it an error: `$('#countdown'+members[i]['id]'])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing more about your problem and what's "not working", I'd assume this to be the issue:

```
$('#countdown['+members[i]['id]']).countDown({
```

Should be

```
$('#countdown['+members[i][id]+']').countDown({
```

Comment: Unless it should be $('countdown' + members[i]['id']).countdown({... and it's in multiple places. The only reason I suggest this is because of this -> members[i]['enddate'];

Comment: yeah it seems you right, it should be `members[i]['id']` instead of `members[i]['enddate']`